# Conversion from Allegro *.brd to *.alg

Tags: orcad, cadence, allegro

Can anyone who works with Cadence Allegro convert a *.brd file to *.alg ?

Comment: probably not anyone, some of the users might not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I can share the instructions of how to do this, but this is not the right forum for asking someone to do a translation for you. Hopefully these instructions will help you to pass the information on to the correct forum, however.

The conversion from *.brd to *.alg requires the use of two files:

- AllegroExportViews.txt
- brd2alg.bat

Please see the bottom of this post for the contents of these files. Note that one must have a valid license for OrCAD/Allegro in order to run the "extracta.exe" command called by "brd2alg.bat". These instructions were written to convert the *.brd file to *.alg for importing into Altium Designer, which is the intent of "AllegroExportViews.txt". However, the resulting *.alg file can be used for other purposes as well.

Follow these steps:

1. Create a local copy of the *.brd file to be converted. For example, create a folder on the desktop titled “To Be Converted” and place the *.brd file inside it.
2. Copy “AllegroExportViews.txt” and “brd2alg.bat” files into the local directory containing the *.brd file to be converted
3. Open a Windows command prompt and navigate to the folder containing the board file to be converted
4. Type the following command (Replace the string between the quotation marks with the actual name of the board file to be converted. Quotes must be kept if the board file name contains spaces, otherwise they may be omitted). Press Enter:

> `brd2alg.bat “brdFileToConvert.brd”`

5. The conversion may take some time. Be sure to wait until the command is finished (i.e. the prompt reappears at the bottom of the terminal window).
6. The *.alg file will be created inside the local directory containing the *.brd file

**AllegroExportViews.txt:**

```
# Start of Allegro to Altium Designer Board View
BOARD
    BOARD_NAME
    BOARD_UNITS
    BOARD_EXTENTS_X1
    BOARD_EXTENTS_Y1
    BOARD_EXTENTS_X2
    BOARD_EXTENTS_Y2
    BOARD_THICKNESS
END
# End of Allegro to Altium Designer Board View

# Start of Allegro to Altium Designer Layer View
LAYER
    LAYER_SORT
    LAYER_SUBCLASS
    LAYER_ARTWORK
    LAYER_USE
    LAYER_CONDUCTOR
    LAYER_DIELECTRIC_CONSTANT
    LAYER_ELECTRICAL_CONDUCTIVITY
    LAYER_MATERIAL
    LAYER_THERMAL_CONDUCTIVITY
    LAYER_THICKNESS
END
# End of Allegro to Altium Designer Layer View

#
# Connectivity - Simple Net list.
#
CONNECTIVITY
  NET_NAME != ''
  CLASS = 'PIN'
  NET_NAME_SORT
  NODE_SORT
  NET_NAME
  REFDES
  PIN_NUMBER
  PIN_NAME
  SUBCLASS
END

#
# Net Rules View
#
NET
  NET_NAME_SORT
  NET_NAME
  NET_STATUS
  NET_CAPACITANCE
  NET_ETCH_LENGTH
  NET_ETCH_WIDTH_AVERAGE
  NET_IMPEDANCE_AVERAGE
  NET_IMPEDANCE_MAXIMUM
  NET_IMPEDANCE_MINIMUM
  NET_INDUCTANCE
  NET_MANHATTAN_LENGTH
  NET_MANHATTEN_LENGTH
  NET_PATH_LENGTH
  NET_PROPAGATION_DELAY
  NET_RESISTANCE
  NET_VIA_COUNT
  NET_BUS_NAME
  NET_PHYSICAL_TYPE
  NET_PROPAGATION_DELAY
  NET_DIFFERENTIAL_PAIR
  NET_DRIVER_TERM_VAL
  NET_ECL
  NET_ECL_TEMP
  NET_FIXED
  NET_LOAD_TERM_VAL
  NET_RELATIVE_PROPAGATION_DELAY
  
  NET_MAX_BVIA_STAGGER
  NET_MAX_FINAL_SETTLE
  NET_MAX_OVERSHOOT
  NET_MAX_PARALLEL
  
  NET_MAX_VIA_COUNT
  NET_MIN_BVIA_GAP
  NET_MIN_BVIA_STAGGER
  NET_MIN_LINE_WIDTH
  NET_MIN_NOISE_MARGIN
  NET_NET_PHYSICAL_TYPE
  NET_NET_SPACING_TYPE
  NET_NO_GLOSS
  NET_NO_PIN_ESCAPE
  NET_NO_RAT
  NET_NO_RIPUP
  NET_NO_ROUTE
  NET_NO_TEST
  NET_PROBE_NUMBER
  NET_RATSNEST_SCHEDULE
  NET_ROUTE_PRIORITY
  NET_ROUTE_TO_SHAPE
  NET_SAME_NET
  NET_SPACING_TYPE
  NET_STUB_LENGTH
  NET_TS_ALLOWED
  NET_VIA_LIST
  NET_VOLTAGE
  NET_WEIGHT

END

#
# Pad Stack View
#
PAD_DEF
END

#
# Board geometries minus symbols.
#
FULL_GEOMETRY

  CLASS != 'PACKAGE GEOMETRY'
  CLASS
  SUBCLASS
  SYM_TYPE != 'PACKAGE'
  RECORD_TAG
  GRAPHIC_DATA_NAME
  GRAPHIC_DATA_NUMBER
  GRAPHIC_DATA_1
  GRAPHIC_DATA_2
  GRAPHIC_DATA_3
  GRAPHIC_DATA_4
  GRAPHIC_DATA_5
  GRAPHIC_DATA_6
  GRAPHIC_DATA_7
  GRAPHIC_DATA_8
  GRAPHIC_DATA_9
  GRAPHIC_DATA_10
  PIN_NUMBER
  PAD_STACK_NAME
  PAD_SHAPE_NAME
  PAD_TYPE
  PAD_FLASH
  DRILL_HOLE_X
  DRILL_HOLE_Y
  NET_NAME
  PIN_X
  PIN_Y
  VIA_X
  VIA_Y

END

#
# Extract footprint (symbol) geometries 
#
FULL_GEOMETRY


  SYM_NAME
  SYM_NAME != ''
  SYM_TYPE
  COMP_DEVICE_TYPE

  REFDES

  CLASS
  SUBCLASS
  RECORD_TAG
  GRAPHIC_DATA_NAME
  GRAPHIC_DATA_NUMBER
  GRAPHIC_DATA_1
  GRAPHIC_DATA_2
  GRAPHIC_DATA_3
  GRAPHIC_DATA_4
  GRAPHIC_DATA_5
  GRAPHIC_DATA_6
  GRAPHIC_DATA_7
  GRAPHIC_DATA_8
  GRAPHIC_DATA_9
  GRAPHIC_DATA_10
  PIN_NUMBER
  PIN_NAME
  PIN_TYPE
  PAD_STACK_NAME
  PAD_SHAPE_NAME
  PAD_TYPE
  PAD_FLASH
  DRILL_HOLE_X
  DRILL_HOLE_Y
  NET_NAME
  PIN_X
  PIN_Y

END

#
# Symbol Instances.
#
SYMBOL
     SYM_TYPE
     SYM_NAME
     REFDES
     SYM_MIRROR
     SYM_ROTATE
     SYM_X
     SYM_Y
     SYM_CENTER_X
     SYM_CENTER_Y
     SYM_LIBRARY_PATH
END
```

**brd2alg.bat:**

```
extracta.exe %1 AllegroExportViews.txt AllegroBoard.txt AllegroLayers.txt AllegroNetlist.txt AllegroNetRules.txt AllegroPadStack.txt AllegroRoutes.txt AllegroSymbolsDefs.txt AllegroSymbolInsts.txt
COPY AllegroBoard.txt+AllegroLayers.txt+AllegroNetlist.txt+AllegroNetRules.txt+AllegroPadStack.txt+AllegroRoutes.txt+AllegroSymbolsDefs.txt+AllegroSymbolInsts.txt AllegroASCII.txt
DEL AllegroBoard.txt AllegroLayers.txt AllegroNetlist.txt AllegroNetRules.txt AllegroPadStack.txt AllegroRoutes.txt AllegroSymbolsDefs.txt AllegroSymbolInsts.txt
MOVE /-Y AllegroASCII.txt %1.alg
```