Cadance to Altium Conversion - Is it Hard?
Does anyone know how much work is required to convert Cadence PCB design files to Altium importable files? I've been told it's the equivalent of 2-3 months of work. I'm slightly dubious but I'm keeping an open mind. I've never used Cadence products before so pardon my misuse of product names.
From my research, I need the following files/

Orcad Schematic capture file (*.dsn, *.olb, *.max, *.llb) - equivalent to Altium *.schdoc file. I'm not sure how this relates to Concept HDL
Allegro board file in ASCII format (*.alg) - equivalent to Altium *.pcbdoc file
Allegro constraint file (*.dcfx) - equivalent to Altium DRC file
Allegro footprint file (*.dra) - equivalent to Altium *.pcblib file

From what I've read, the only file that needs to be converted from its native cadence format is the Allegro board file (*.brd), which needs to be converted to an ASCII format using the Extracta tool within Allegro. This seems like it is probably closer to a day or two worth of work. Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

It feels like it would be in the best interest of the respective tool vendor to provide an import feature of other common formats...

FWIW, I just had a consultant convert a pretty complex PCB (4 layers, lots of RF including PCB antennas, ~400 components, several fine pitch QFP/QFN) from an obscure CAD program to Altium and it was some 2-3 weeks of work until first prototype. I'm counting on at least 2 prototype board spins though, so the work is not done. But then this consultant already had in-depth knowledge of everything that the board does. For someone who doesn't, then several months doesn't sound far-fetched.

I have performed this very conversion on multiple occasions. The conversion is the easy part, and Altium is able to pull in the design within a matter of minutes. The tedious part, however, is checking the imported files to make sure everything was pulled in as desired. The cleanup task could take anywhere from an hour to a couple of weeks. In my experience it only took a few hours to clean up the design, but your mileage may vary depending on the complexity of the design.
The Allegro constraint file (.dcfx) and the Allegro footprint file (.dra) are not required for the import. However, you may import the symbols and footprints separately if you like. I generally avoid importing them at the same time as the board in order to keep the process simple.
Bear in mind, however, that Altium does not accept the native OrCAD/Allegro .brd file. Instead, as referenced in your question, it requires the .alg ASCII version. You will require an active OrCAD license in order to run the extracta.exe command. This is the tool which converts the .brd binary file to a .alg ASCII file format. This command is run from the Windows command line, but the conversion only takes a few minutes. Please refer to the following answer for instructions:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/701558/41856
Good luck!

Thanks for the information; it's good to have some context about where these dates might come from from an unbiased third party. I figured the conversion was the easy part and the massaging was the tricky part.
